# Can you change the _id autoincrement field in SQLite (Android)?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an Android app with SQLite and use the following line when creating the table:

```
_id integer primary key autoincrement
```

My question is, can I do an update on this row and change the _id if my user wants to?  So, for example, I'll have two records in the DB:

```
1 My First Record
2 My Second Record
```

Now after my update, I'd like something like:

```
1 My First Record
38 My Second Record
```

Will SQLite allow this and easily adapt?  i.e. the next primary key autocreated will be #39?

Comment: I don't if such thing is possible or not, but you shouldn't change that value even if it possible. To achieve such thing please consider to create you own ID field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [documented](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html), changing the `_id` is allowed and will update the autoincrement sequence properly.

Just try it:

```
$ sqlite3
SQLite version 3.7.16 2013-01-11 09:58:54
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> CREATE TABLE MyTable(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT);
sqlite> INSERT INTO MyTable DEFAULT VALUES;
sqlite> INSERT INTO MyTable DEFAULT VALUES;
sqlite> UPDATE MyTable SET _id = 38 WHERE _id = 2;
sqlite> INSERT INTO MyTable DEFAULT VALUES;
sqlite> SELECT * FROM MyTable;
1
38
39
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do such things, you'll have to manage the autoincrement by yourself. SQLite will **not** allow you to change the value of autogenerated field. Another approach is to add another field and use it instead.

Also, if there is some kind of workaround, I can assure you it's not a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should never modify primary keys this way, e.g. think of foreign keys etc. Sqlite won't allow this.
2. Apart from that, the auto increment counter is stored in a seperate table and has no idea what you are doing. Even if it was allowed to change the primary key, the counter would remain unaffected.